# How does $#array work in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays

In the following example:

```
my $info = 'NARIKANRU';
my @first_one = split /,/, $info;
print "$first_one[$#first_one]$first_one[$#first_one-1]\n";
```

The output is:

```
NARIKANRUNARIKANRU
```

I am not sure if this is correct because there is only one element in `@first_one` and `$#first_one` is the index of that element.

Given that `$#first_one` is not equal to `$#first_one - 1`, why is the single element in `@first_one` being printed twice?

Comment: Why do you think the output is wrong?

Comment: because i have only one word . But while printing the array twice

Comment: @CHEE Do you realize that the one elemenet of `@first_one` appears twice in your print statement: `$first_one[$#first_one ].$first_one[$#first_one-1]`

Comment: But in the array i have only one element

Comment: got it !!! thanks for teaching this kid :-)

Comment: I do not think this question warrants closing. It turned out to be a question about a subtle aspect of array indexing in Perl (even thought the question itself was badly composed). @CHEE: Next time, don't throw in so many red herrings into the mix.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The output is correct. There are no commas in `$info` so `split` returns a list consisting of a single element.

`$#first_one` is the index of the last (and in this case also first and only) element of `@first_one`. With a single element, `$#first_one` is `0`. Therefore, `$first_one[$#first_one]` is `$first_one[0]`.

Also, `$first_one[$#first_one-1]` is `$first_one[-1]`, i.e. the short hand way of referring to the last element of an array.

<s>Of course, things would not have worked out this way had [$[](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%36%91) been set to some other value than the default.</s> *Apparently, things work unless `$[` is negative.*

See also [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Variable-names).

Finally, you ask if there is anything wrong in your code. From what I can see, you are not using [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html). You should.

Comment: Using array indexes less than $[ but >= 0 doesn't work so well - the results may not be what you expect.  Though I'm not sure what you could realistically expect.

Answer (score 3):

`$#array` just gives you the last index in the array that contains a value where `@array` returns you the size of the array when used in a scalar context, which would return you 1 greater than that.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@array = ();
push(@array,10);
push(@array,11);

print $#array, "\n";         # Prints 1
print scalar(@array), "\n";  # Prints 2
print $array[$#array], "\n"; # Prints 11 (i.e. the last element)
```

Having stated that, you're split is creating a list of only one element.  So  `$#array` is going to provide you 0.  Accessing an array with the subscript -1 will also give you the last element in your array, which b/c you only have one in your array, the expression `$#info - 1` equates to `-1` (i.e. the last item in your array)

If you were to have 2 elements in your array, say:  dog, cat.  Then `$#array` would yield cat while `$#array - 1` would yield dog because you wouldn't be producing `-1` with your expression `$#info - 1`.

Comment: @array returns the size when used in scalar context, so you may need to be careful and use scalar(@array) (or 0+@array)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to write:

```
@first_one = split('', $info);
```

to get a list of characters?